# Angular Routing not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs

I am currently using routeProvider to load a partial in the usually way. This works in Chrome, however, this does not work in Internet Explorer 11.

The links are in the form href="#/routehere", and it works when I manually paste the URL into the browser, but not when I click on the links.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: can you share the routing part of the code that you have written? or make a plunker and comment the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have missed this one

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"> #  Angular Docs says
```

OR you may try adding this to the header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```